# Unity Netcode PlayerObjects empty after spawning on NetworkManager

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, networking, multiplayer, ownership

I'm starting to learn Unity's Netcode for online multiplayer games.

I have a simple 2D scene where players can connect and control their own square. That works fine and everything gets synched between them.

I want to spawn monsters that get controlled by the server. Now, I get stuck commanding the monsters to walk to the nearest player.

My idea:

- Make sure only the server controls the monster (in OnNetworkSpawn)
- Let the server search for the nearest player (in RecalculateNearestPlayerServerRpc)
- Move the monster towards the nearest player (in Update)

My problem is that while trying to get all `PlayerObjects` the respective variables in the `ConnectedClientsList`of the `NetworkManager` is `null`:

```
NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList[0]
{Unity.Netcode.NetworkClient}
    ClientId: 0
    OwnedObjects: Count = 0
    PlayerObject: null
NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList[1]
{Unity.Netcode.NetworkClient}
    ClientId: 1
    OwnedObjects: Count = 0
    PlayerObject: null
```

Here is the code for my `MonsterController`:

```
public class MonsterController : NetworkBehaviour
{
    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private float speed = 10.0f;

    void Awake()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn()
    {
        if (!IsServer) enabled = false;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        RecalculateNearestPlayerServerRpc();
        var dir = nearestPlayer.transform.position - transform.position;
        rb.velocity = dir * speed;
    }


    [ServerRpc]
    private void RecalculateNearestPlayerServerRpc()
    {
        float nearestPlayerDistance = float.MaxValue;
        foreach (NetworkClient client in NetworkManager.Singleton.ConnectedClientsList)
        {
            float sqrDistance = (client.PlayerObject.transform.position-transform.position).sqrMagnitude;

            if (sqrDistance < nearestPlayerDistance)
            {
                nearestPlayerDistance = sqrDistance;
                nearestPlayer = client.PlayerObject;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I spawn and give ownership like this:

```
public class GameManager : NetworkBehaviour {
    [SerializeField] private PlayerController _playerPrefab;

    public override void OnNetworkSpawn() {
        SpawnPlayerServerRpc(NetworkManager.Singleton.LocalClientId);
    }   

    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
    private void SpawnPlayerServerRpc(ulong playerId) {
        var spawn = Instantiate(_playerPrefab);
        spawn.NetworkObject.SpawnWithOwnership(playerId);
    }

    public override void OnDestroy() {
        base.OnDestroy();
        MatchmakingService.LeaveLobby();
        if(NetworkManager.Singleton != null )NetworkManager.Singleton.Shutdown();
    }
}
```